# Angular 1.6 component bindings return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have set up an example where I wish to pass an ID to my component. It is my understanding that using two-way data binding I would call the component like so

Template File:

```
<div ng-controller="searchCtrl as vm">
    <search-condition id="vm.id"></search-condition>
</div>
```

When defining the controller, I specify that I want a two way binding between the components through the vm.id like so.

```
comp.component('searchCondition', {
    templateUrl: 'Core/Views/search-condition.html',
    bindings: {
        id: '='
    }
});
comp.controller('searchConditionCtrl',function($scope){
    var vm = this;
    this.$onInit = function() {
        console.log(vm.id);
    };
});
```

When attempting to output the value of vm.id all I receive is 'undefined'. Also when I try and output the value through {{vm.id}} no data is output, suggesting the data never arrives in the component.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `id` is the best attribute name

Comment: I've tried several from data,id,searchId, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a value through props the variable changes to the prop name.

Example

Usage

```
<search-condition prop="data"></search-condition>
```

In SearchCondition

```
<div>{{prop}}</div>
```

This will show the data value as data is being assigned to prop

Now there is one Angular thing you need to know here. With Components Angular 1 defaults the controllerAs value with $ctrl so if SearchCondition is a component and not a directive prop would be `{{$ctrl.prop}}`

In your case try `{{$ctrl.id}}` and it should show up in the template of search-condition

If you want to change the default value of controllerAs just define it when you create the component like this.

```
.component('myCoolComponent', {
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: { ... }
})
```

If it is defined like this {{vm.id}} would work.

I would suggest looking at the Docs for all the options you have when defining a component and what the defaults are.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: When I try and output the data using {{vm.id}} (with the controllerAs: 'vm' set), {{$ctrl.id}}, {{id}}, nothing return's the data, this is why I'm confused because from my understanding I've set it up correctly

Comment: I found out the issue when I deleted my whole html file and replaced it with {{vm.id}} I had '<div ng-controller="searchConditionCtrl as vm">' at the top of my file and it seem to have been interfering with the data coming through. Thank you for the help